# Unit Testing method failing with lambda expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, rhino-mocks

I am trying to write a unit test.

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    _mocks=new MockRepository();
    MockFactory.Reset();
    _scheduledOrderprovider = new ScheduledOrderProvider();
    _scheduledOrderRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ScheduledOrderRepository>(); 
}

[TestMethod()]
public void GetScheduledOrderMessageStatusIDsTest()
{                
    int NofOrdersPerMessage = 1;
    int[] expected = GetMockScheduledOrderMessageStatusIDs(NofOrdersPerMessage);
    _scheduledOrderRepository.Expect(x => x.GetOrderMessageStatusIDs(1)).Return(expected);
    int[] actual=_scheduledOrderprovider.GetScheduledOrderMessageStatusIDs(NofOrdersPerMessage);
    _scheduledOrderRepository.VerifyAllExpectations();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected[0], actual[0]);
}
```

It's failing with the below error:

> expression cannot contain lambda expressions rhinomock

Comment: The error seems to be coming from RhinoMock not MS Test. Also, you don't need MS in the title. Keep tags, well, in the tags.

Comment: We need more information. Does it fail when you compile the unit test project, or when you run this unit test? Can you post the exact error message and the call stack or build output? Also, how does _scheduledOrderRepository get passed to _scheduledOrderprovider?

Comment: If you are getting an exception, can you post that and its stack trace?